# Ktor client: how to remove(not include) REQUEST/FROM log

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

the request code

```kotlin
var myClient: HttpClient = HttpClient(Android) {
    // Logging
    install(Logging) {
        logger = Logger.ANDROID
        level = LogLevel.BODY
    }
}
```

when try to request URL

```kotlin
myClient.get("https://www.sample.com/state")
```

try to run the request and got the following request log

```
2022-07-05 11:20:58.667 977-1021/? W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - REQUEST: https://www.sample.com/state
2022-07-05 11:20:58.667 977-1021/? W/System.err: METHOD: HttpMethod(value=GET)
2022-07-05 11:20:58.667 977-1021/? W/System.err: BODY Content-Type: null
2022-07-05 11:20:58.667 977-1021/? W/System.err: BODY START
2022-07-05 11:20:58.667 977-1021/? W/System.err: 
2022-07-05 11:20:58.667 977-1021/? W/System.err: BODY END
```

response log

```
2022-07-05 11:20:58.924 977-2181/? W/System.err: [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - RESPONSE: 200 OK
2022-07-05 11:20:58.924 977-2181/? W/System.err: METHOD: HttpMethod(value=GET)
2022-07-05 11:20:58.924 977-2181/? W/System.err: FROM: https://www.sample.com/state
2022-07-05 11:20:58.924 977-2181/? W/System.err: BODY Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2022-07-05 11:20:58.924 977-2181/? W/System.err: BODY START
2022-07-05 11:20:58.924 977-2181/? W/System.err: "idle"
2022-07-05 11:20:58.924 977-2181/? W/System.err: BODY END
```

In the log, show the request URL `https://www.sample.com/state` twice.

For security reasons, we don't want to display this URL in the log.

**How do I set or operate not to display this URL?**

the kotlin version and ktor version

```
def kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

def kotlinx_coroutines_version = '1.6.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinx_coroutines_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlinx_coroutines_version"

def ktor_version = '2.0.2'
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
// HTTP engine: The HTTP client used to perform network requests.
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version"
// Logging
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"
```

Comment: Remove LogLevel.BODY. By removing this your request won't show in logs.

Comment: but other than the URL, all content is required @pratik vekariya

Comment: I mean you dont need to add level. I have done in java, If you want to see it i can show you.

Comment: try to remove the `LogLevel.BODY`, the log level change to default(ALL), the log content everything.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZWxY.png Check this screenshot, in this i have added only networkConnectionInterceptor. And its not showing requests in logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write your own interceptors and log only desired information (you can use the [source code of the Logging plugin](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/3a4d5a9fe9dc96eb49272e77cbb9010accb8bde7/ktor-client/ktor-client-plugins/ktor-client-logging/common/src/io/ktor/client/plugins/logging/Logging.kt) as an example) or write a logger that will remove unwanted information from messages. The latter solution is naive and fragile:

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.okhttp.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

suspend fun main() {
    val myLogger = object : Logger {
        private val urlRegex = Regex("""FROM: .+?$""", RegexOption.MULTILINE)
        private val delegate = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpClient::class.java)!!
        override fun log(message: String) {
            val strippedMessage = urlRegex.replace(message, "FROM: ***")
            delegate.info(strippedMessage)
        }
    }

    val client = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
        install(Logging) {
            logger = myLogger
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
    }

    client.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will customize my logger interface according to this idea.