# on(ResponseSent) is triggered twice on custom Unauthorized status page

Tags: ktor

I have a custom plugin that has this code

```
on(ResponseSent) {
        it.application.log.info("RESPONSE SENT!!!!")
}
```

And then I have the Status page plugin with this in the configuration

```
status(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { call, status ->
        call.respondText(text = "UNAUTHORIZED!!!", status = status)
    }
```

When I issue an unauthorized request, "RESPONSE SENT!!!!" it is being logged twice.  How can I stop this from happening?

Edit:  Here's a unit test showing this behavior. If you remove the status page plugin, you'll see the test will pass.

```
    @Test
    fun responseSentShouldOnlyBeCalledOnceWithStatusPagePluginInstalled() = testApplication {
        //given
        var numTimesResponseSentCalled = 0
        val ResponseSentPlugin = createApplicationPlugin(name = "ResponseSentPlugin") {
            on(ResponseSent) {
                numTimesResponseSentCalled++
            }
        }
        application {
            install(StatusPages) {
                status(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { call, status ->
                    call.respondText(text = "UNAUTHORIZED!", status = status)
                }
            }
            install(ResponseSentPlugin)
            install(Authentication) {
                bearer {
                    authenticate {
                        null
                    }
                }
            }
            install(Routing) {
                authenticate {
                    post("/foo") {
                        call.respondText("bar")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //when
        client.post("/foo")

        //then
        assertEquals(1, numTimesResponseSentCalled)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ktor client: how to remove(not include) REQUEST/FROM log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72863763/ktor-client-how-to-removenot-include-request-from-log)

Comment: OP of my suggested thread had said that "In the log, show the request URL https://www.sample.com/state twice. " Which I suspect you are seeing a log twice? so let me know if that article answered your question.  ty

Comment: @easleyfixed Thanks for your comment.  I don't think my thread is related.  It seems like the other OP want to prevent https://www.sample.com/state from showing up in his logs.  I updated my post with a unit test showing this bug.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, sorry it didn't help, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The `ResponseSent` hook is implemented as an interception of the `ApplicationSendPipeline` at the `Engine` phase. At this phase, the server engine sends a reply to the client through a network (except for the test engine). Every time the `ApplicationCall.respondText` or any other `respond` method is called, the `ApplicationSendPipeline` gets executed.

In the case you have, the `Authentication` plugin responds with the 401 status code by executing the `ApplicationSendPipeline`. The `StatusPages` plugin executes the pipeline one more time in its status handler. Since the second execution doesn't cancel the first, the `Engine` phase is hit twice, so is your callback. In order not to send a response twice to the client, Ktor checks whether the response has been handled (committed). The following diagram shows how the pipeline gets executed.

```
                  ApplicationSendPipeline
Authentication -> |->|--|--|--|--------| 
                             After   Engine
                              |
                              |
                           StatusPages -> ApplicationSendPipeline
                                          |->|--|--|--|--------|
                                                             Engine
```

To solve the problem, define and use a hook that intercepts `ApplicationCallPipeline` before the `Engine` phase.

```
object BeforeSend : Hook<(ApplicationCall) -> Unit> {
    override fun install(pipeline: ApplicationCallPipeline, handler: (ApplicationCall) -> Unit) {
        val phase = PipelinePhase("BeforeSend")
        pipeline.sendPipeline.insertPhaseBefore(ApplicationSendPipeline.Engine, phase)
        pipeline.sendPipeline.intercept(phase) {
            handler(call)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you must check whether the call is committed to avoid executing a code inside the handler twice.

```
val ResponseSentPlugin = createApplicationPlugin(name = "ResponseSentPlugin") {
    on(BeforeSend) { call ->
        if (!call.isHandled) {
            numTimesResponseSentCalled++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.  I tried your solution and it works to make the unit test pass, however it didn’t work on my original use case.  My use case is to simply log when the response has been sent to the client, along with the response status.  When using on(ResponseSent), it would always log twice on unauthorized, but would correctly log the response status.  With the provided solution, it logs one time, but now, the response status is null.  How can I get it to log one time and show the response status?

Comment: Unfortunately, you either log a committed response status twice or the `null` value because the `call.isHandled` is always `true` after sending a response.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was trying to figure out this exact problem. Any custom response sent using the `StatusPages` plugin causes the `CallLogging` plugin to fire a second time. The other answer is spot on regarding the pipelines, it was super helpful and pointed me in the right direction. However, as seen in the answer's comments, a new issue emerges. While it is true that failure messages are now logged once, successful calls will have a `null` status unless you explicitly set one in your `respondX()` calls.

In the case that you only need to log the request, you can conditionally call `proceed()` on the `ApplicationCallPipeline` in your phase interceptor. This will cause the `Engine` phase to run if there is no status, essentially using a default status and sending the response.

```
if (call.response.status() == null) proceed()
```

After adding this line, your interceptor should look something like this:

```
object BeforeSend : Hook<(ApplicationCall) -> Unit> {
    override fun install(pipeline: ApplicationCallPipeline, handler: (ApplicationCall) -> Unit) {
        val phase = PipelinePhase("BeforeSend")
        pipeline.sendPipeline.insertPhaseBefore(ApplicationSendPipeline.Engine, phase)
        pipeline.sendPipeline.intercept(phase) {
            // some calls may only have a status after they are sent
            if (call.response.status() == null) proceed()
            handler(call)
        }
    }
}
```

By ensuring that the call is committed before logging, we can assume there will only ever be one "handled" instance. This allows us to simply check for `call.isHandled` and the status will never be null:

```
val ResponseSentPlugin = createApplicationPlugin(name = "ResponseSentPlugin") {
    on(BeforeSend) { call ->
        if (call.isHandled) {
            // log your request here
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to see an example, you can find my implementation [here on GitHub](https://github.com/sandrabot/visualize/blob/3beffaf8e6b9ca17974af19c06c4ba8f48ad3de2/src/main/kotlin/plugins/Logging.kt).